# Getting information of linked topics on a single request

Tags: freebase

So, say I search for a City using Freebase API. Say, San Francisco:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0d6lp?limit=20&filter=/common/topic/description&filter=/common/topic/article&filter=/location/location/geolocation&filter=/location/location/containedby&filter=/travel/travel_destination/tourist_attractions

I get a bunch of data, including the '/location/location/containedby', which refers by which other entities this one is contained by. This is how I can find out to which State and Country the city belongs to.

The problem is that I only get those entities name and mid, but not '/common/topic/notable_for', therefore, I have to make separate queries per each entity, asking just the notable_for property, to find out which one of those is a Country, a State, or other stuff I don't need.

In example, this is one of the queries, which determines United States of America is a country:
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/09c7w0?filter=/common/topic/notable_for
This is executed between 3 to 6 times each city.

Is there a way to tell the API to include more information about these linked entities on a certain Topic? Like on this case, to include '/common/topic/notable_for' on linked entities. It would save tons of queries, and time to the end user in my case.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually get these results using the new [output parameter](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-output) on the [Freebase Search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview). Like this:

```
query=/m/0d6lp
output=(description /location/location/geolocation (/location/location/containedby notable))
```

[Try it out](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=/m/0d6lp&output=%28description%20/location/location/geolocation%20%28/location/location/containedby%20notable%29%29)

Comment: Ah, great! I appreciate both of your responses, though this solution is closer to my current implementation. And gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the MQL Read API if you want better control on the information returned.  Then you can specify nested queries that ask for the contained_by locations to be returned with their types (or you can explicitly filter to only those which are a country or a state).